# Navbar problems with code, js is not connected good

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Hi I have problems with code, I just copied all js and its still not working. I dont know what is missing there. I think its good connected to the js.
https://bootstrapious.com/p/transparent-navbar
My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header class="header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top py-3">
        <div class="container"><a href="#" class="navbar-brand text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Transparent Nav</a>
            <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
            
            <div id="navbarSupportedContent" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active"><a href="#" class="nav-link text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link text-uppercase font-weight-bold">About</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>

<script>
  $(function () {
    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        if ( $(window).scrollTop() > 10 ) {
            $('.navbar').addClass('active');
        } else {
            $('.navbar').removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
</script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/font-awesome.min.css"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This appears to work correctly in codepen (see: https://codepen.io/j0r_dan/pen/gOjOOYP). Are you correctly importing all required scripts and CSS. From the code above, there is no bootstrap.css which I would expect, unless it's inside style.css

Comment: I just copied all resources from the website. I created foulder "js" then i created 4 .js files and copy the code to them from link.

Comment: So I am not sure if i understand this question, what else I need too add there.

Comment: Can you explain what is happening or not happening? Screen shots maybe?

Comment: Yes sorry, when I open index.html i see this: https://ctrlv.cz/W3Xl

Comment: Yeah, you're missing some stylesheets, likely bootstrap. Try adding `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">` to your `head`

Answer (score 0):

**Please include custom script after the Js library. Please check below code and make sure all js files are loading well in the browser.**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <header class="header">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top py-3">
            <div class="container"><a href="#" class="navbar-brand text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Transparent Nav</a>
                <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
                
                <div id="navbarSupportedContent" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active"><a href="#" class="nav-link text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link text-uppercase font-weight-bold">About</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Gallery</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Portfolio</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    
    
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/font-awesome.min.css"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
          $(window).on('scroll', function () {
              if ( $(window).scrollTop() > 10 ) {
                  $('.navbar').addClass('active');
              } else {
                  $('.navbar').removeClass('active');
              }
          });
      });
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```